# Yii2. Incorrect representation of bootstrap nav-tabs class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2

I have bootstrap tabs:

```
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

But this code renders following:

[image]

But on bootstraps website it looks like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this in yii2?

Comment: For me it is working fine.Check you are using any other css

Comment: there is an extension for yii2 that help you to create tabs try with that.it's here http://demos.krajee.com/tabs-x